# Getting "Use of unresolved identifer" - can't find .json file?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working through the SwiftUI tutorial by Apple trying to replicate their process. At the point: Building lists and navigation, section 2. and 2.4, it says:

"When you add the landmark property, the preview stops working, because the LandmarkRow type needs a landmark instance during initialization."

When I replicate their fix, namely modify the preview provider and adding the name of the .json file where the database is stored, I get the aforementioned alert.

It seems like Xcode doesn't recognize the name of the .json file. How do I fix this?

I have no idea why this doesn't work.

```
struct GrapeRow_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GrapeRow(grape: grapeData[0])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Landmark tutorial there is a file with all the landmarks namely `Resources/landmarkData.json` which is loaded into the array using the `load()` function in `Models/Data.swift`. I believe that that function is sufficiently general for you to be able to use for your grapes but you'll need to try and see. That part of the tutorial was prepared beforehand.

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried adding that but now it says "Cannot preview in this file - NameofApp.app may have crashed"

Comment: Happens to me all the time ;^( New beta today so maybe it will work otherwise you can use the simulator.